# What is the new user interface that services like Google/Google+ are using?

Tags: website-design, menu, css, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the top navigation called when it is common to a network or suite of websites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/what-is-the-top-navigation-called-when-it-is-common-to-a-network-or-suite-of-webs)

Recently Google/Google+ and other services have adjusted their menus to the top of the screen. I am wondering what this interface style is called, if it has a name? Is it done through javascript, css or both? And what are other people's thoughts on it? Is it better for users?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: You mean the bar on the top of their network of sites that shows the number of notifications you have in a convenient red circle? [Innovative of them](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/) :)

Comment: See also: UX SE question *What is the top navigation called when it is common to a network or suite of websites?*  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/what-is-the-top-navigation-called-when-it-is-common-to-a-network-or-suite-of-webs

Comment: @DevinDixon I've closed this as a duplicate but if this is not what you meant, please ask a new, more specific question.